# UWP Customize button Flyout

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I have a button flyout when i click flyout show. I can reposition flyout on button i click? I use Gridview and datatemplate in itemtemplate have button i want button flyout will be on button i click. I can do it with flyout button? If not what control i can do it?

[image]

```html
<Grid Width="230" Height="230"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="White"
                BorderThickness="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                    Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}"
                    Content="&#xE712;"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <Flyout>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid Width="230" Height="230">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="0">ạkdasdjhas</Button>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="1">123123123</Button>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="2">dfsdfsdfsd</Button>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="3">qưewqeqwe</Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontSize="20"
                               Margin="0,5,0,0"
                               FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontSize="15"
                               Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontSize="15"
                               Margin="0,5,0,0"
                               Foreground="Gray"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: What did you try already? Can you show us your code?

Comment: I added my code

Comment: @DMT `Flyout` has [`Placement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.placement). for your scenario, you could set it as `Bottom`.